# Cant select NUCLEO-L433RC-P in Keil

Tags: stm32, keil, nucleo

I recently received NUCLEO-L433RC-P, which I want to start using with the Keil application. I installed the STM32L4xx_DFP package, but I can't select the board under the "Manage Run-Time Environment" settings.

[image]

Would anybody know, what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try selecting the chip.

Comment: I'm following a video tutorial series, where it is shown, that there should be a dropdown menu in the "Manage Run-Time Environment" Board support section. Upon clicking on the Variant field, no other options are shown. That is why I believe, I'm probably missing something.